# Dlib whl for python 3.7

Tags: object, detection, python-3.7, dlib

I know there's a whl file for python3.6. I don't want to downgrade to 3.6 or run in a virtual environment.

Soo my question is why hasn't anyone made the whl file available rather than downloading 4.4gb of ms vc that i know i won't beer using after compiling dlib.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it . Install Visual Studio 2019 and CMake . Then go to folder of your dlib , open the terminal and command `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` . It will load lots of text , and then you will have a wheel file in your dist folder . Good luck!